# Component tGoogleAdWordsReport started failing with API exception

Tags: talend, google-ads-api

tGoogleAdWordsReport have been working well for a month, downloading daily a report for the previous day. But recently it started failing with exception:
`com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.utils.ReportException: Problem sending data to report download server`

Any ideas on the reasons of this sudden break?

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @Sharad idk -- I don't work with Talend anymore :)